# Access items in yaml map within the same yaml file

Tags: yaml

I want to define a map in my yaml file to be utilized within the yaml file.

Note: We have a preprocessing step with our yaml that essentially lets us insert replaceable tokens. I want to use the value that a token is replaced with as my key... that's why I don't know what value I want while I am writing the yaml, just FYI

So in short what I would like to do is something like this

```
keyMapping: &mapping
key1: value1
key2: value2

myValue : *mapping.key1
```

or

```
keyMapping: &mapping
key1: value1
key2: value2

myValue : *mapping[key1]
```

or

```
keyMapping: &mapping
key1: value1
key2: value2

myValue : *mapping["key1"]
```

My desired outcome would be

```
keyMapping: &mapping
key1: value1
key2: value2

myValue : value1
```

However using https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/

I can see that none of those are valid. Is this even possible in yaml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access only the `value` of a `key-value` pair of an anchored(&) map by using alias(*).

But you can do it like below:

```
keymap:
  <<: &flag
    key1: value1
  key2: value2

myvalue : *flag
```

This will set `myvalue` to `key1: value1`. Now as you want only `value1` to be the value of `myvalue`.

```
keymap:
  key1: &flag value1
  key2: value2

myvalue : *flag
```

For more examples and details description visit 
[YAML - Anchors, References, Extend](https://blog.daemonl.com/2016/02/yaml.html)